# C# Pass FILE STREAM to EXE file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, upload, filestream

I have an a FILE STREAM  that I want to pass to an EXE to be processed. Is this possible?

```
 using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
         Addfile(fs, fileinmemory.ToString());
        }

 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = Addfile  //filestream from above
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "load.exe"; //used withabove argument to be passed into exe
 p.Start();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`simple :`
mempry mapped files.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately however, the link is dead.  Perhaps the following link may be used as an alternative to the reader: https://gunnarpeipman.com/csharp-memory-mapped-files/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible, not directly through the command line.

The arguments expected are *command line arguments*, normally in C# and C based applications this would be a `string[]`.

If you were to use a file that was accessible to both processes you would need to pass the file path (or have a pre-agreed file location), then you could use that, but this is not the same as passing in a stream to an executable.

Comment: Well could you pass it another way (other than arguments?)

Comment: Not with the `Process` class, not directly anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file physically and pass it's path, or you can create a memory mapped file for exchange